# Django Sentry server hangs

Tags: django, sentry

I installed Sentry v2.0, django 1.3, and python 2.7

I run sentry start, then I visit my server url at 0.0.0.0:9000 where it just hangs. Sometimes I get a HTTP code 302, other times I get a HTTP code 200 (output to the console). Any ideas?

My ~/.sentry/sentry.conf.py looks like:

```
import os.path
from sentry.conf.server import *
ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'sentry',
        'USER': 'myusername',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
SENTRY_KEY = 'my-key'
SENTRY_PUBLIC = True
SENTRY_WEB_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
SENTRY_WEB_PORT = 9000
```

In my settings.py file I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = {
    ...
    'sentry',
    'raven.contrib.django',
    ...
}
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'medium': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s (%(module)s): %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {

        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        ...
    }
}


SENTRY_KEY = 'my-key'
SENTRY_SERVERS=['0.0.0.0:9000']
SENTRY_CLIENT='raven.contrib.django.DjangoClient'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that setting `SENTRY_WEB_HOST` to '`0.0.0.0`' makes it listen on all network interfaces, but that isn't a valid address itself.

Try reaching the server using `localhost:9000` or `127.0.0.1:9000`